Create a formula that gathers information from one sheet and inputs it in another based on one cell
I have two spreadsheets. I am scanning items onto sheet 2 under column A.
On Sheet 1 I have all the information for Inventory. The Columns I will be using from sheet a is Column D and Column AA. So when I am scanning items on sheet to and a number from Column AA matched from Sheet 1 it will pull the information from Column D from the same row and be put in column C on sheet 2. I have a formulas but its not pulling the information needed
Not Found appears but there are matches
=IF(A2="", "", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, Woo!$D$2:$AA$1000, 4, FALSE), "Not Found"))

From your description, it seems that you're trying to look into column AA and returning value from column D; if that is the case, VLOOKUP in this way wouldn't be helpful, because it looks in the first column of the range (D) and return from the 4th column (G).
I suggest you to use XLOOKUP, that you can set an input and an output range, like this:
=IF(A2="", "", IFERROR(XLOOKUP(A2, Woo!$AA$2:$AA$1000,Woo!$D$2:$D$1000), "Not Found"))

In fact, you can use this function to return "Not found" without IFERROR:
=IF(A2="", "", XLOOKUP(A2, Woo!$AA$2:$AA$1000,Woo!$D$2:$D$1000,"Not found"))


Thank you so much Martín!!!! It worked!
